# require_once not working

Tags: pages, page-template, include

I have a custom page template, and this template need to include one php file. I tried to put this script

```
require('.../hc-v2-child/ayah.php') and this require(__DIR__.'ayah.php');
```

in functions.php and in the custom page template, but I'm getting this error

```
[07-Oct-2015 04:15:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/folder/folder1/public_html/folde3/wp-content/themes/hc-v2-childayah.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /folder/folder1/public_html/folde3/wp-content/themes/hc-v2-child/page-mylogin.php on line 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you are trying to include is in child theme folder then try following:

`require(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ayah.php');`